# Tensorflow stratified_sample error

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm trying to use `tf.contrib.training.stratified_sample` in Tensorflow to balance classes. I made a quick example below to test it, drawing samples from two unbalanced classes in a balanced way and verifying it, but I'm getting an error.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes

batch_size = 10
data = ['a']*9990+['b']*10
labels = [1]*9990+[0]*10
data_tensor = ops.convert_to_tensor(data, dtype=dtypes.string)
label_tensor = ops.convert_to_tensor(labels)
target_probs = [0.5,0.5]
data_batch, label_batch = tf.contrib.training.stratified_sample(
    data_tensor, label_tensor, target_probs, batch_size,
    queue_capacity=2*batch_size)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    d,l = sess.run(data_batch,label_batch)
print('percentage "a" = %.3f' % (np.sum(l)/len(l)))
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "/home/jason/code/scrap.py", line 56, in <module>
    test_stratified_sample()   
File "/home/jason/code/scrap.py", line 47, in test_stratified_sample
    queue_capacity=2*batch_size)   
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/training/python/training/sampling_ops.py", line 191, in stratified_sample
    with ops.name_scope(name, 'stratified_sample', tensors + [labels]):   
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 829, in binary_op_wrapper
    y = ops.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=x.dtype.base_dtype, name="y")   
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 676, in convert_to_tensor
    as_ref=False)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 741, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)   
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 113, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)   
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 102, in constant
    tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))   
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 374, in make_tensor_proto
    _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)   
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 302, in _AssertCompatible
    (dtype.name, repr(mismatch), type(mismatch).__name__)) TypeError: Expected string, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message' instead.
```

The error doesn't explain what I'm doing wrong. I also tried putting the raw data and labels in (without converting to a tensor), as well as tried using `tf.train.slice_input_producer` to create an initial queue of the data and label tensors.

Has anyone gotten `stratified_sample` to work? I haven't been able to find any examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've modified the code into something that works for me. Summary of the changes:

- Use `enqueue_many=True` to enqueue a batch of examples with different labels. Otherwise it's expecting a single scalar label Tensor (which can be stochastic when evaluated by the queue runners).
- The first argument is expected to be a list of Tensors. It should have a better error message (I think this is what you ran into). Please do send a pull request or open an issue on Github for a better error message.
- Start queue runners. Otherwise code that uses queues will deadlock. Or use `Estimator`s or `MonitoredSession` so you don't need to worry about this.
- (Edit based on comments) `stratified_sample` does not shuffle the data, it just accepts/rejects! So if your data is not randomized, consider putting it through `slice_input_producer` (`enqueue_many=False`) or `shuffle_batch` (`enqueue_many=True`) before sampling if you want it to come out in a random order.

Modified code (improved based on Jason's comments):

```
import numpy
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes

with tf.Graph().as_default():
  batch_size = 100
  data = ['a']*9000+['b']*1000
  labels = [1]*9000+[0]*1000
  data_tensor = ops.convert_to_tensor(data, dtype=dtypes.string)
  label_tensor = ops.convert_to_tensor(labels, dtype=dtypes.int32)
  shuffled_data, shuffled_labels = tf.train.slice_input_producer(
      [data_tensor, label_tensor], shuffle=True, capacity=3*batch_size)
  target_probs = numpy.array([0.5,0.5])
  data_batch, label_batch = tf.contrib.training.stratified_sample(
      [shuffled_data], shuffled_labels, target_probs, batch_size,
      queue_capacity=2*batch_size)

  with tf.Session() as session:
    tf.local_variables_initializer().run()
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    coordinator = tf.train.Coordinator()
    tf.train.start_queue_runners(session, coord=coordinator)
    num_iter = 10
    sum_ones = 0.
    for _ in range(num_iter):
      d, l = session.run([data_batch, label_batch])
      count_ones = l.sum()
      sum_ones += float(count_ones)
      print('percentage "a" = %.3f' % (float(count_ones) / len(l)))
    print('Overall: {}'.format(sum_ones / (num_iter * batch_size)))
    coordinator.request_stop()
    coordinator.join()
```

Outputs:

```
percentage "a" = 0.480
percentage "a" = 0.440
percentage "a" = 0.580
percentage "a" = 0.570
percentage "a" = 0.580
percentage "a" = 0.520
percentage "a" = 0.480
percentage "a" = 0.460
percentage "a" = 0.390
percentage "a" = 0.530
Overall: 0.503
```

Comment: If I change
`data = ['a']*9990+['b']*10
 labels = [1]*9990+[0]*10`
to
`data = ['a']*9000+['b']*1000
  labels = [1]*9000+[0]*1000`
in your code, it breaks and only produces class 1 examples ("a"s). Your code does work as posted, but I can't figure out why the above change (which obviously makes it more realistic, in that the batch size is much less than the number in either class) would break it. It's also more balanced, yet the result is completely unbalanced.

Comment: Fantastic point, should have caught that. `stratified_sample` does not _shuffle_, it just accepts/rejects. So if the input is in a non-random order, the output will be too. I've added a shuffling step to the example with a high `min_after_dequeue` to make sure the data is shuffled before sampling. This was a problem even with the higher imbalance, it just got hidden because so many of the majority class were discarded.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: For completeness, as I'd prefer a single example output (for file loading, augmentation, etc.), I replaced
`shuffled_data, shuffled_labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch(...)`
with
`shuffled_data,shuffled_labels = tf.train.slice_input_producer([data_tensor, label_tensor], shuffle=True, capacity=3*batch_size)`
and set enqueue_many to false. This is faster (~9s vs.120s), since it rejects single examples rather than full batches.

Comment: Huh, that is quite a bit faster. I've edited the answer to incorporate your improvement. I'm somewhat surprised, since `stratified_sample` does re-batch the data, so it isn't rejecting whole batches.